# Java 8 streams and maps worth it?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

It feels like java 8 streams and mapping functions are so verbose they aren't really an improvement. For example, I wrote some code that uses a collection to generate another, modified collection:

```
private List<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    List<DartField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : model.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
            fields.add(DartField.getDartField(field));
        }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

This seems like the ideal use case for java 8 streams and their functions, so I rewrote it like that:

```
private List<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return Arrays.asList(model.getDeclaredFields())
            .stream()
            .filter(field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
            .map(field -> DartField.getDartField(field))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But I'm not sure I like that more. It's 236 characters as compared to 239 in normal-style java. It doesn't seem more or less readable. It's nice that you don't have to declare an `ArrayList`, but needing to call `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and `Arrays.asList` (depending on the data type) isn't any better.

Is there some practical improvement to using `.stream()` like this that I just don't get, or is this just a fun way to throw any coworkers for a loop who don't know functional programming?

I suppose if I were dynamically passing around filter or map lambdas it would be useful, but if you don't need to do that ...

Comment: Imho it's much more readable because you can see at once that the data are filtered and mapped. You don't really know what's happening in your first example until you've gone through the whole code. Now imagine something more complex.

Comment: A few years later I've converted to using functional programming for this kind of process most of the time, but with Kotlin. In Kotlin this kind of operation is succinct, looks nice, and it has tons of great convenience methods like `mapNotNull` `flatMap` etc.

Comment: The first example is much clearer. Don't use streams. Most systems today look aweful because of post java 7 programmers making an entry and jumping onto the streams immediately and keeping up with it. 90% of systems today look aweful becaues of that. java is not a language for this level of functional programming. I have no iterations of lists in my code anywhere, yet with people that rely on streams you see this kind of iteration all the time, because they think it is convenient.

Comment: And @abetteroliver Rarely are there ever more complex scenarios. In fact, the only the times I've seen plenty of complex scenarios like the ones you mention is in code written by people that overdo the streams thing. They do this constantly and filter all the the time, over and over again. Often lengthy statements. Then good luck refactoring and breaking out all those lambdas. Are you one of those? Real hardcore Java developers that made an entry to Java post Java 11 are rare to be seen. Any new entrant will start using stream and get stuck in that world. Building a codebase based on them.

Comment: And never getting out and just getting themselves deeper and deeper in ****. The only way you can deal with this is the hard way. Completely forbid its usage. Otherwise it is a slippery slope. And trust me, my code is a polished Ferrari. It would never have been if I relied on Java Streams.

Comment: @mjs Could you give us some evidence to back up your statements? It can be misused is not a good argument. Java in general is misused by many. I also think it would be better to comment on the existing answers if you have an opposing opinion.
People on SO haven't seen your code, so why should anyone trust you, that your code is a polished Ferrari, whatever that means? Not that I think this is not the case, but this is something you simply cannot ask for.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the `Stream` API *consistently*. You are restricting the use case to something which can be best described as “actually not using the `Stream` API” as you are insisting on returning a `Collection`. That’s especially absurd as it’s a `private` method so you are entirely able to adapt the callers as well.

Consider to change the method to

```
private Stream<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return Stream.of(model.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
            .map(field -> DartField.getDartField(field));
}
```

and look what the *caller(s)* actually want to do. Usually they don’t need a `Collection` as an end in itself, but want to perform an action or even more operations which could be chained, e.g. print them:

```
getDartFields(Foo.class).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The most interesting feature is the lazy nature of the stream, which implies that upon `getDartFields` return, no action has been performed yet and if you use operations like `findFirst`, there is no need to process all elements. You’ll lose this feature if you return a `Collection` containing all elements.

This also applies to multi-step processing where processing ordinary lists implies that for each step a new list has to be created and populated with results.

Comment: Good (great) answer. Because it is verbose unless the new lazy paradigm is used. I'd have to wonder why the Java 8 crew didn't make a few functions intrinsic on Arrays and Lists, etc.? All arrays could have 'foreach' , 'filter', 'map' as first class methods. Java has a long way to go to achieve concision! Until then, Stream.of( ... )  will be our new friend.

Comment: Looking through my code, you are correct that if I systematically switched to using Streams they would be more interesting and beneficial. On the other hand all of those operations in this case would end with me needing to call `.collect` or `.reduce`, so my private method really should return a `List<DartField` as that can be used to generate new streams multiple times.

Comment: @Saint Hill: in principle, as arrays are (special) classes which can implement interfaces, all arrays could implement `List` as `add` and `remove` are specified as optional so arrays don’t need to support them. Being a `List` would imply that they have a `forEach` and a `stream` method…

Comment: Absurd is a bit harsh. I've found problems passing streams and forth, mainly because people end up traversing it more than once, so we tend to concretize before leaving method scope.

Comment: @orbfish: that’s a statement specific to this scenario. Still, if you need a materialized collection in some cases, there is no need to let the `private` method return a collection in all cases. The caller still can collect if needed.

Comment: I can do all of the above in a for loop 10 times cleaner.

Comment: @mmm how do you implement “all of the above” in a loop when you don’t know which terminal operation the caller will actually append? The whole point of this answer is that a consistent use of the stream API is to return a Stream because the caller can decide to chain, e.g. `.findFirst()` or `.parallel().toArray()` or `.sorted(…).limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList())`, which do entirely different things.

Answer (score 9):

You can write it differently (not necessarily better)

```
private List<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return Stream.of(model.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
            .map(DartField::getDartField)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using static imports this looks like

```
private static List<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return of(model.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(field -> !isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
            .map(DartField::getDartField)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

> It doesn't seem more or less readable.

This is often the case IMHO.  However, I would say that in >10% of cases it is significantly better.  Like any new feature, you will probably over use it to start with until you get familiar with it and find you use it the amount you feel comfortable with.

> Is there some practical improvement to using .stream() like this that I just don't get, or is this just a fun way to throw any coworkers for a loop who don't know functional programming?

I suspect both.  If you don't know functional programming, it tends to be read only code.  i.e. you can still understand what it does, the problem is if you have to maintain it.

IMHO, it is worth encouraging developers to learn functional programming as it has some very useful ideas about how to structure your code and you would benefit from it even if you didn't use FP syntax.

Where the Streams API is useful in constructs you previously wouldn't have bother implementing.

E.g. say you want to index the field by name.

```
private static Map<String, DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return of(model.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(field -> !isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
            .map(DartField::getDartField)
            .collect(groupingBy(f -> f.getName()));
}
```

In the past you might have used a List instead of a Map, but by making the assembly of Map easier you might use the data structure you really should be using more often.

Now lets see if it would be faster if we used more threads.

```
private static Map<String, DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return of(model.getDeclaredFields()).parallel()
            .filter(field -> !isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
            .map(DartField::getDartField)
            .collect(groupingByConcurrent(f -> f.getName()));
}
```

See how hard that was, and changing it back when you find it probably does more harm than good, is pretty easy too.

Comment: It's too bad I can't accept multiple answers on this one. A lot of people make good points I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 streams are particularly verbose, most due to converting to a stream and then back to another structure.  In FunctionalJava, the equivalent is:

```
private List<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return List.list(model.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
        .map(field -> DartField.getDartField(field))
        .toJavaList();
}
```

I warn against just counting characters as a measure of complexity.  This barely matters.

Functional programming allows you to reason about your code using a simple substitution model, rather than having to trace through your entire program.  This makes your program more predictable and easier because you need fewer pieces of information in your head at once.

I also warn against returning streams.  Streams are not arbitrarily composable, streams are mutable data where callers have no way of knowing if a terminal operation has been called on the stream.  This means we need to know the state of the program to reason about what is happening.  Streams were introduced to help eliminate mutable state, but are implemented using mutable state - far from ideal.

If you want an immutable stream, I recommend Functional Java's stream, https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/fj/data/Stream.html.

Comment: I see no danger stemming from consumed streams---that's trivially detectable and debuggable, plus that sort of error doesn't really happen in practice. Plus, I actually *respect* the way the Streams API approaches mutability: it offers the performance advantages of mutability, but puts the actual mutation under strict control.

Comment: The FJ Stream, from the looks of it, imposes serious memory overheads, just like Clojure's lazy collections. This is exactly the pitfall avoided by Java's streams. BTW it is interesting to note that Rich Hickey's *Reducers* are a conceptual adaptation of Java's Streams API, with the same advantages.

Comment: The danger from streams is exactly the argument of mutability vs immutability.  Java 8 argues in favour of streams to avoid mutability, but doesn't take this idea far enough.  Streams are only useful in a limited scope because the type don't enforce type safety.

Comment: Yes, that would surely sum up the position of the statically-typed FP camp. Java's type system is weak in many other ways as well and the way the Streams API is designed meshes quite well with everything else. I find the API to be a very good fit for the Java ecosystem and most of its advantages are not related to static type safety.

Comment: Marko, perhaps you could expand on this point or provide a link on why it imposes serious memory overheads.  I don't see how this occurs, unless the stream is cached.

Comment: Well, isn't it cached? The docs say it is a lazily materialized linked list. So if you hold on to the head of the stream, you cause the retention of the complete list. If you don't retain the head, then you just create a lot of garbage.

Comment: You're right Marko, the streams are memoised (cached) as they are incrementally computed.  Of course intermediate values are garbage collected.  You can always incrementally build the function that you later use to transform the stream, which helps in many use cases.

Comment: Yes, I have worked with this model for five years in Clojure. It is very convenient wherever performance is not key, but it does entail significant overheads compared to the approach with a single-step eager reduction of the original input. Especially, if you compare an `IntStream`-based solution with a `Stream<Integer>`, the difference is between minimal O(1) garbage and some 100 bytes of garbage per element. Locality of reference is compromized as well.

Comment: Plus, note that the concern of "losing the head" of the stream is a thorny one: for example, you can't store the stream in a final local variable. You are at the mercy of the runtime even for variables which have left their scope. JVMs do not take specific care of this concern because it is not very relevant to idiomatic Java. That's a typical syndrome plaguing all kinds of "JVM languages"---the actual JVMs are actually tightly coupled to the use cases occurring in plain Java.

Comment: I don't think the analogy with Clojure holds. Reducers complement the out of the box behaviour for use in those cases when seqs don't have the required performance. Streams, on the other hand, just replicate what is already available via Iterators (well, mostly, we need Spliterators for the parallel stuff). That's a pretty marginal return.

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically constrain your use case to just what you have posted, then a Stream-based idiom is not substantially better. However, if you are interested to find out where the Streams API is a true benefit, here are some points:

- the Stream-based idiom can be parallelized with no virtually effort on your part (this is actually the strongest reason why Java got lambdas in the first place);
- Streams are composable: you can pass them around and add pipeline stages. This can greatly benefit code reuse;
- as you already noted, you can also pass around lambdas: it is easy to write template methods where you plug in just one aspect of processing;
- once you are comfortable with the idiom, FP code is actually more readable as it is more closely related to the *what* instead of the *how*. This advantage increases with the complexity of the processing logic.

I would additionally note that the difference in readability is more a historical artifact than intrinsic to the idioms: if developers were taught FP from the start and worked with it day-to-day, then it would be the imperative idiom which was odd and hard to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Not worth it if you insist on getting back to collections. However, you have missed an opportunity - consider the following and you should see where using streams adds a level of flexibility and composability to your code:

```
private static final Predicate<Field> isStatic
        = field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers());

private Stream<Field> getDeclaredFields(Class<?> model) {
    return Stream.of(model.getDeclaredFields());
}

private Stream<Field> getStaticFields(Class<?> model) {
    return getDeclaredFields(model).filter(isStatic);
}

private Stream<DartField> getDartFields(Class<?> model) {
    return getStaticFields(model)
            .map(field -> DartField.getDartField(field));
}
```

The point is that you can use streams **as** collections instead of mechanisms to build new collections.

By allowing all of the natural methods to just fall out of the algorithm you end up with patently obvious code that is almost inevitably reusable and each component naturally does its one thing.

Comment: Instead of your `getStaticFields(Stream)` I would strongly prefer just storing the lambda: `public final Predicate<..> isStatic = field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())`. That's important because with your model you get prefix notation whereas with this approach you could have `getDeclaredFields(model).filter(isStatic)`. Similar for other methods.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - That is an elegant step towards the much nicer prefix notation. It looks like a small back-step though as I was trying to demonstrate passing streams around as a better approach. It does nicely introduce lambdas into the mix though so I will change the code.

Comment: Indeed, I choose to pass the whole stream only when the method does more than add a single step to the pipeline. When you get into serious composition, you gradually start hating every place you are forced to pass in the stream. If anything, that's one point I love about Clojure---you can chain anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 the team took an Object oriented programming language, and applied the "Objectification" to produce Functional Object oriented programming(lol...FOOP). It will take some time to get used to this, but I argue that *any and all* hierarchical Object manipulation should remain in its **Functional state**. From this perspective Java feels like it bridges the PHP gap; Allow the data to exist in its natural state, and mold it into the application GUI.

This is the true philosophy behind an API creation from a Software Engineering perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(model.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
        .map(DartField::getDartField)
        .toList();
```

I think it's shorter/simpler, comparing to original for loop.

```
List<DartField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : model.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
        fields.add(DartField.getDartField(field));
    }
}
return fields;
```

The more important thing is more flexible. Jut think about if you want do more filter/map, or sort/limit/groupBy/..., you just need to add more stream API call, and code still keep concise, the nested for loop/if else will become more and more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, java stream APIs(map, filter, forEach, groupBy...) actually facility data handling in the process of daily development. Instead of getting your hands dirty, you just tell the stream APIs what you want not how to do.

However, I'm not comfortable when reading the java codes populated with various related stream APIs. Sometimes, it's very wired when using stream APIs in the code format and layout, especially along with the function program. Shortly, it degrades the readability.